# How to create a bitmap temp file and get the path WebApi C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dropbox-api

I'm using a DropBox API just for tests and I need to save some images from my WebApi, the problem is I need to have a stringPath to make the upload, but since the Bitmap image will be "stored" inside of my model, I need to create a tempFile with a unique name for that image, so I could get a path and upload the image!

This is how upload :

```
async Task Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file, string content)
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
    {
        var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
            folder + "/" + file,
            WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
            body: mem);
        Console.WriteLine("Saved {0}/{1} rev {2}", folder, file, updated.Rev);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you from your code that why do you want to have temp file

Comment: Because, Im using WebApi, I send an image from my AndroidClient, and then I need to send to DropBox, I cant' pass the stringPath because there's none, when I make a POST request to my API, i have something like this : 

`private string UserName {get;set;}`
`private Bitmap ImageUser {get;set}`
Here's the Image!

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstanding on `path` argument for `UploadAsync()` method.

It's not a source path to local file that you're going to upload.

It's a **destination path** to remote file in user's Dropbox. See [Dropbox documentation](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_UploadAsync_1.htm) for details.